# can't serialize class com.google.code.morphia.mapping.Mapper

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I use morphia to do operations in Mongodb ... 
I get the following error when i try to insert a iterator into db

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't serialize class com.google.code.morphia.mapping.Mapper
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder._putObjectField(BasicBSONEncoder.java:270)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putObject(BasicBSONEncoder.java:174)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putObject(BasicBSONEncoder.java:120)
    at com.mongodb.DefaultDBEncoder.writeObject(DefaultDBEncoder.java:27)
    at com.mongodb.OutMessage.putObject(OutMessage.java:289)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:261)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:226)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:147)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:90)
    at com.google.code.morphia.DatastoreImpl.insert(DatastoreImpl.java:703)
    at com.google.code.morphia.DatastoreImpl.insert(DatastoreImpl.java:681)
    at com.google.code.morphia.DatastoreImpl.insert(DatastoreImpl.java:676)
    at DB_Write.writeData(DB_Write.java:35)
    at MongoOperation.main(MongoOperation.java:17)
```

Help with me it .. 
Thanks in advance ..

Comment: it looks like you have a Mapper reference on one of your entities which makes no sense.  What does that class look like?

Comment: this is the oly entity class 

public class Cll10 {
 @Id
 private  ObjectId id;
 
 private String deId;
 private String devName;
 private Long timeStamp;
}

Comment: Can you share MongoOperation.main() ?